# How do you get IntelliJ to insert a 'for' loop snippet?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

How do you get snippets in IntelliJ for standard dart programming constructs.

For example if I type `for` in VSCode, I can press tab and VSCode would save me time by giving me a default implementation...for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
}
```

*community edition, with dart and flutter plugin installed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ it is called [Live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html). 
You can find it in `Preferences` > `Editor` > `Live Templates`.

Here is an example to create a `fori` template that create your for loop.

[image: live template example]

Comment: Thank you! in the list there is also an itara and an iter which I hadn't noticed (it's a small list for my liking and in comparison to out of the box VSCode but I guess we can easily add some new ones)